# Counting variable with various length in data frame using table() in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a method for **counting valuables occurrences in the data frame column** without using any loop.
Values in the data frame have various lengths, which make it for **table()** function.

The data in the data frame looks like this *(below in the code block)*. Additionally, there will be even more values in a single vector, than the locally demonstrated maximum.

I'm planning to use the result as an input for a chart.

```
[[1]]
[1] "Brazil"

[[2]]
[1] "Mexico"

[[3]]
[1] "Singapore"

[[4]]
[1] "United States"

[[5]]
[1] "United States"

[[6]]
[1] "Turkey"

[[7]]
[1] "Egypt"

[[8]]
[1] "United States"

[[9]]
[1] "India"

[[10]]
[1] "India"

[[11]]
[1] "United States"

[[12]]
[1] "Poland"        "United States"

[[13]]
[1] "Mexico"

[[14]]
[1] "Thailand"

[[15]]
[1] "United States"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` the `list` column and apply the `table`

```
table(unlist(df1$col1))
```